# symfony2 relation between two entities

Tags: symfony, entities, relation, between

i am started to learn symfony2, Here i have some basic doubts on entity relations. Totally i have two entities 1.Admission.php and 2.Mstcity.php , just i wanna make relation between these two entities. 
mysql Table structure:1.admission= id, name , mst_city_id  2. mst_city = id,city_name .. just i am having simple admission form. in that form i need to load the city_name select box . the relation id is in admission table mst_city_id is foreign key of mst_city table  .

admission.mst_city_id=mst_city.id         ...... > need city_name by this matching

just help me to understand this process

Answer (score 1):

There's no point for me to repost here the symfony docs, so go ahead and read them [HERE](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations)  There are examples in the docs that show exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have proper Associations set in place, you can just add the field with entity as widget type

```
$builder->add('mst_city_id', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'BundleName:mst_city',
    'property' => 'city_name',
));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should check which type of relations you use -One2One, One2Many, Many2Many
2. Define relations in mappers/annotations and check for owned side
3. Create form types and bind data from it to entities
4. Persist and flush entities